# Control RGB LEDs ON/OFF - A smarter way than using "if"? (Arduino, C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, arduino, switch-statement, led

I want to control three RGB LEDs in color (eff. 9 LEDs in total) and whether to be on or off. I am using Arduino with PlatformIO and the FastLED library to turn them on using *FastLED.show();*.

There are **six buttons** on my display: *LED1*, *LED2*, *LED3*, *RED*, *GREEN*, *BLUE* (dual state buttons) which give me

**true** when pressed and

**false** when released

```
void bt0PopCallback(void *ptr){uint32_t dual_state; NexDSButton *btn = (NexDSButton *)ptr; bt0.getValue(&dual_state); if(dual_state){ LED1 = true; } else{ LED1 = false; } }
void bt1PopCallback(void *ptr){uint32_t dual_state; NexDSButton *btn = (NexDSButton *)ptr; bt1.getValue(&dual_state); if(dual_state){ LED2 = true; } else{ LED2 = false; } }
void bt2PopCallback(void *ptr){uint32_t dual_state; NexDSButton *btn = (NexDSButton *)ptr; bt2.getValue(&dual_state); if(dual_state){ LED3 = true; } else{ LED3 = false; } }
```

E.g.: *LED1 = true* when LED1 button is pressed, *LED1 = false* when button is released.

If LED1 = true and RED = true, this led shall turn red. When RED is released and GREEN is pressed the LED1 is now green. If LED1 is released and LED2 is pressed LED1 goes off and LED2 turns on GREEN.

I came up with this one:

```
if(BLUE == true){BLUEV = 255;} else { BLUEV = 0;}
if(RED == true){REDV = 255;} else { REDV = 0;}
if(GREEN == true){GREENV = 255;} else { GREENV = 0;}

if(LED1 == true){leds[0] = CRGB(REDV, GREENV, BLUEV); } else { leds[0] = CRGB(0, 0, 0); }
if(LED2 == true){leds[1] = CRGB(REDV, GREENV, BLUEV); } else { leds[1] = CRGB(0, 0, 0); }
if(LED3 == true){leds[2] = CRGB(REDV, GREENV, BLUEV); } else { leds[2] = CRGB(0, 0, 0); }
FastLED.show();
```

but it's obviously imperfect, I reckon.

Anyone has suggestions how to code it better? Maybe using a switch case?

Cheers!

Comment: What are the types of `{BLUE, RED, GREEN}`, `{LED1, LED2, LED3}` and `leds`? You're testing these against `true` so it looks like Booleans, correct? Please update all the relevant information in the question. Also, mention the C++ standard you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I made a bit clearer.

Comment: By _types_ I meant how these identifiers have been declared? And, C++98/03/11/14/17, which one - the one that you're currently using on that platform? Please update that. If you could show a bit more of your code that'd be great to understand it better.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I am using the Arduino environment in PlatformIO. Not sure there are different C++ types? The declaration is code from the Nextion display series. Sorry for being am a programming noob.

Comment: For starters, you can change `if(dual_state){ LED1 = true; } else{ LED1 = false; }` to simply `LED1 = dual_state;`. You don't need `if-else` here at all.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can assign `dual_state` to the corresponding LED without `if-else` in your callbacks.

Here's an example:

```
void bt0PopCallback( void* ptr )
{
    uint32_t dual_state;
    NexDSButton* btn = (NexDSButton*) ptr;
    bt0.getValue( &dual_state );
    LED1 = dual_state;                          // direct assignment
}
```

For other `if-else` variants in your code for colors, you can use the ternary operator `?:` to clean things up like this:

```
BLUEV  = BLUE  ? 255 : 0;
REDV   = RED   ? 255 : 0;
GREENV = GREEN ? 255 : 0;
```

And, for setting the values of `leds` array, use a `for` loop. The `LED1`, `LED2`, and `LED3` may be grouped using an [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to be used in the loop for the corresponding values of `leds`.

Here's an example with `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

const std::array<decltype(LED1), NUM_LEDS> LED { LED1, LED2, LED3 };

for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; ++i )            // loop to set the colors of LEDs
{
    leds[i] = LED[i] ? CRGB(REDV, GREENV, BLUEV) : CRGB(0, 0, 0);
}
```

`NUM_LEDS` represents the size of the `leds` array i.e.:

```
#define NUM_LEADS 3

CRGB leds[NUM_LEADS];
```

Comment: Thanks. It complains and underlines "LED" when implementing           

leds[i] = LED[1] ? CRGB(REDV, GREENV, BLUEV) : CRGB(0, 0, 0); 

with 

error: no match for 'operator[]'

Comment: @nolimits: Forgot about that. Updated.

Comment: Thx. On a closer look, its pretty much the same what I had above. Do you think there is a different way to implement such a function?

Comment: You're welcome! I believe that that was the goal to implement the same observable behavior. Which function?

Comment: @nolimits: Share your relevant code with some online compiler.

Comment: I forgot the #include <array>.  So what it does is it replaces LED[1] with the LED1 variable?

Comment: @nolimits: So, it's working now? Right now, it makes an array of LED objects by copying them and uses that in the loop for automating everything. Go through the documentation of `std::array` for more details on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I will have to deal with 10000 leds later, is there a better way than creating 10000 objects in the list?

Comment: @nolimits: You need to share the declarations of LED objects and how they're used in your code - the relevant parts of your code.